# "not sure whether it WAS" vs. "not sure if it WERE"

Tags: grammar, subjunctive-mood, irrealis-were

Which of the two is correct:

1. I was not sure whether it WAS the other car's coupler or mine that had suddenly had trouble connecting.
2. I was not sure if it WERE the other car's coupler or mine that had suddenly had trouble connecting.

This is a story told by a car (trains).

Answer (score 3):

In third-person past-tense singular **subjunctive**, you use **were** to describe an unreal or imaginary scenario that didn't happen in the past.  You might say,

> If the other car **were** moving faster, I would not have had trouble connecting.

But since in your sentence you're just using third-person past-tense singular, non-subjunctive, you should use **was**, because the example is not a hypothetical or unreal scenario, it is merely unknown.

> I'm not sure if **it *was* the other car**.

I recommend inspecting the fascinatingly convoluted definition of *be*, to see how it's used in different tenses and forms:

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/be?s=t