# "If were" and "if was" in the same sentense. What's the deal with that?

Tags: grammar

A quote from Fahrenheit 451:

> If there **were** no war, if there **was** peace in the world, I'd say fine, have fun!

Comment: What if it were:  *If there were no bugs, if it was nice out, we could open the windows.*

Comment: I'd say it's an unacceptable twinning of alternative forms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["not sure whether it WAS" vs. "not sure if it WERE"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/386350/not-sure-whether-it-was-vs-not-sure-if-it-were)